Prove that second derivative operator is unbounded on Banach space
I need to prove that $A=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ is unbounded on Banach space $C_{\infty}(R)$.
Can I just take the $f(x)=\ln{x}$ and say that $f''(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}$ is not bounded on $[0,1]$?

No. Your function isn't smooth everywhere (eg at zero). This is not all though, since any smooth function will have a smooth, and thus bounded, derivative. You need to use the definition of unbounded: specifically, you need to find a family of smooth functions on the unit ball (so norm 1) where the supremum over the norms of the derivatives of said family is unbounded. I would recommend looking at a proof for the case of the (first) derivative, and then try to modify that proof for the second derivative.

@BrevanEllefsen , can you give me more hints? And I need second derivative, not the first one. Will $y=x^{\frac{3}{2}}$ work? Its second derivative is infinite at $x=0$.

No. I gave plenty in the comment above, and the fact your new attempt is entirely invalid for the same reasons I already listed implies to me you didn't read (or at least understand) what I wrote at all. Please consult a textbook or notes on this subject and use the definition.

The question is asking you to show that the operator $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}:C^\infty(\mathbb R)\to C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is unbounded, not that there is some function in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ which is unbounded

Furthermore, what norm are you putting on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ since you're claiming it's a Banach space?

This is quite strange. No “natural” norm will make $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ a Banach space. Its usual topology only makes it into a Fréchet space, but not a Banach space.

The question is asking you to show that the operator $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}:C^\infty(\mathbb R)\to C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is unbounded, not that there is some function in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ whose second derivative is unbounded (which your counterexample also does not show, as the logarithm is not in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$). We thus need to recall what it means for an operator to be bounded:

Definition. If $V,W$ are normed spaces, we say that a linear map $T:V\to W$ is bounded if there exists some constant $C>0$ such that
$$\lVert Tv\rVert_W\leq C\rVert v\rVert_V$$
for all $v\in V$.

What is not clear in your question is what norm you are putting on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, however we can actually prove that $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}$ is unbounded regardless of the norm. Suppose we take some arbitrary norm $\lVert\,\cdot\,\rVert$ on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, and consider the family of functions $\{f_\lambda\}_{\lambda>0}$ in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ given by
$$f_\lambda(x)=e^{\sqrt{\lambda} x}.$$
Then we have that
$$f''_\lambda(x)=\lambda e^{\sqrt{\lambda}x}=\lambda f_\lambda(x).$$
If we assume for a contradiction that the operator $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}$ was bounded (and let $C>0$ be a bound as in the definition above), then we would have that
$$\lambda \lVert f_\lambda\rVert=\lVert f''_\lambda\rVert\leq C\lVert f_\lambda\rVert$$
for all $\lambda>0$, so in particular we would have $\lambda\leq C$ for all $\lambda>0$. This is clearly a contradiction.
